# How to Scroll to Bottom of Grid using ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJs. I want my scroll still in the bottom (last row) when i click 'add' button on my grid. I do some code like this:

```
xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add',
        iconCls: "icon-grid-add",
        id: 'ReqAddBtn',
        handler: ReqWinAdd,
        listeners: {
            'click': function () {
                var records = Ext.getCmp('prGrid').getStore().data.length + 1;
                Ext.getCmp('prGrid').getView().focusRow(records);
            }
        }
```

i created event click like that. It works when the first click. But when the next click, the scroll is moving up.

What should i do to make scroll always still in the bottom of grid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preferred way is to get the grid view and scroll it:

```
grid.getView().scrollBy(0, 999999);
```

or

```
grid.getView().scrollBy(0, 999999, true);
```

if you want to animate the scroll

Comment: Yes it works, thanks so much. But i want to ask something, What is the meaning with 0 and 999999? is it code or parameter of "bottom"?

Comment: It is offset in pixels for x and y axes. No horizontal scroll (0), "infinite" vertical scroll 999999. See [scrollBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-scrollBy) documentation for details.

Comment: Now i'm understand. Thanks so much @Saki

Comment: holly molly! Saki hit StackOverflow - game over!

Comment: Yeah, I've been member for years but not active.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i've got the answer.

I change my event to:

```
var scrollPosition = 100;   
YourGrid.getEl().down('.x-grid-view').scroll('bottom', scrollPosition, true);
```

it makes the scroll still in the bottom of the grid. Thanks people.